# Vector space over complex numbers is also a vector space over the real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

So I know I need to prove the kajillion axioms of vector space like commutativity, associativity, the additive/multiplicative identities/inverses etc. How would I go about getting started?

Comment: You don't need to prove any of them. It's given by the fact that it is a complex vector space. The only thing is that you choose not to multiply with scalars with nonzero imaginary part.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're saying. So if I had some vector z = a + bi, I drop the scalar b?

Comment: @Will, if all those properties hold for complex scalars, in particular they will hold for real scalars.

Comment: No. Not the vectors. You just forget (no, not really, it's useful even when you consider it as a real vector space) that you can multiply a vector with all complex numbers, $(x+iy)\cdot \vec{v}$, and restrict yourself to multiply only with real numbers. The addition of vectors is completely detached from the scalars anyway, so all those axioms remain satisfied. The complex multiplicative unit $1$ is contained in the subset $\mathbb{R}$, so that remains too. All other things hold for all complex scalars, so a fortiori for real scalars.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation, Daniel.

Answer (score 2):

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.  Then for any subfield $K \subset \mathbb{C}$, $V$ is also a vector space over $K$.  Proof:

All the relevant axioms of a vector space definition are

> Distributivity of scalar multiplication with respect to vector addition : $a(u + v) = au +av$
>   Distributivity of scalar multiplication with respect to field addition : $(a + b)v = av + bv$
>   Compatibility of scalar multiplication with field multiplication : $a(bv) = (ab)v$

(for all $a,b \in K, v\in V$)

The first one is satisified since it's already satisfied for all $a\in \mathbb{C}$ and $K \subset \mathbb{C}$.  Actually they're all satisfied because $a,b \in K \subset \mathbb{C}$.  Then since $K$ is a field by definition, we're done.

Answer (score 0):

At your level, I suggest you prove $\mathbb{C}$ is also a vector space (of dimension 2) over $\mathbb{R}$ first. Once you "go through" the axioms and see how easy the proof is, then apply the same argument to any complex vector space. This is more complicated than it should be, but might be more helpful to you.